# Get the serial ARM CPU information with a C/C++ program

Tags: c++, c, arm, raspberry-pi

I can get the serial ARM CPU (Raspberry Pi) information with a C/C++ program.
I could get this information from /proc/cpuinfo but then it is very easy to hack the program.
Does anyone know how can the serial number obtained through C/C++?
I want to use the serial number for cryptographic operations.

Comment: Using a serial number for cryptographic operations is an even worse idea that using it for identity -- serial numbers are easy to predict, and provide no secrecy.

Comment: The file */dev/random* strives to try and provide cryptographic type seeds.  It is highly unpredictable on many systems.  Generally, you use public and private keys or [Diffie Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) for verification.  Some CPUs provide zeroizable memory with hardware tamper protection if you are trying for client authentication.  For the ARM, [tag:trust-zone] can provide access to client keys.  But, I don't believe the raspberry-pi has these features?

Answer (score 3):

This one is easy: Start with `fd=fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");`

What I ofcourse mean, that to distrust `/proc/cpuinfo` means to distrust the running kernel - under this premise, all bets are off.

If you want to build a DRM system (i.e. software bound to a physical device), please remember: The first rule of DRM is, that DRM doesn't work.